# CurvedNavigationBar default item

Tags: flutter

Upon login, the user is automatically directed to the dashboard page (usually the middle icon, the third one).
The user arrives well on this page, but the first icon is selected automatically (instead of the third), how to solve this?

Thanks

```
  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Member member;
  _HomePageState({this.member});
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  int selectedPage = 0;
  List _pageOption;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageOption = [
      InsightPage(),
      TradesPage(),
      DashboardPage(member),
      PerformencePage(),
      SettingsPage(),
    ];
    selectedPage = 2;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pageOption[selectedPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        height: 50,
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        items: [
          Icon(Icons.insights, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.list, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.speed, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.settings, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
        ],
        color: secondColor,
        buttonBackgroundColor: secondColor,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedPage = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use the index attribute of the `curved_navigation_bar` library.

**index**: index of NavigationBar, can be used to change current index or to set initial index

Refer this - https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `int selectedPage = 0` to `int selectedPage = 2`.

Does it work for you?

Comment: I've already tried, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Change index please

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        height: 50,
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        index:2 // add change here
        items: [
          Icon(Icons.insights, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.list, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.speed, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.settings, color: Color(0xffffae88), size: 30),
        ],
        color: secondColor,
        buttonBackgroundColor: secondColor,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedPage = index;
          });
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use pageView and set initail page to 2. then for the Nav bar Use what @jahidul Islam use